# How to use std::foreach with parameters/modification

Tags: c++, stl, loops, enumeration

I've found myself writing

```
for(int i=0;i<myvec.size();i++)
   myvec[i]->DoWhatever(param);
```

a lot, and I'd like to compress this into a `foreach` statement, but I'm not sure how to get `param` in there without going super-verbose. I've also got things like

```
for(int i=0;i<myvec.size();i++)
   if(myvec[i]->IsOK())
      myvec[i]->DoWhatever(param);
```

and I'd like to rewrite that guy too. Any thoughts?

Oh, also, for various reasons, I don't want to use boost.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

class X
{
    public:
        void doWhat(int x) {}
        bool IsOK() const {return true;}
};
class CallWhatIfOk
{
    public:
        CallWhatIfOk(int p): param(p) {}

        void operator()(X& x) const
        {   if (x.IsOK())    {x.doWhat(param);}}
    private:
        int param;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<X>      myVec;

    std::for_each(  myVec.begin(),
                    myVec.end(),
                    std::bind2nd(std::mem_fun_ref(&X::doWhat),4)
                 );


    std::for_each(  myVec.begin(),
                    myVec.end(),
                    CallWhatIfOk(4)
                 );
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> Oh, also, for various reasons, I don't want to use boost.

Valid decision, but most likely the wrong one. Consider Boost as an extension to the STL. C++ is a library-driven language. If you don't take this into account, your code will be qualitatively inferior.

While `std::for_each` can be used here, the absence of lambda expressions in C++ until C++0x makes this tedious. I advocate using [Boost.ForEach](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/foreach.html)! It makes this *much* easier:

```
foreach (yourtype x, yourvec)
    if (x.IsOK())
        x.Whatever();
```

Comment: Alas, it's not my decision whether to use boost.

Comment: Might want to say that you *can't* use boost then. Saying you don't *want to* is just asking for an argument... ;)

Answer (score 4):

My preferred solution is usually to write a functor to do what I need:

```
struct doWhatever {
  doWhatever(const Param& p) p(p) {}
  void operator(MyVec v&, Param p) {
    v.DoWhatever(param);
  }

private:
  Param p;
};
```

And then the loop:

```
std::for_each(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), doWhatever(param));
```

Depending on how many variations of this you have, this might be a bit too verbose.
There are plenty of options for doing it inline though.
boost::lambda would let you construct the function you need at the call-site. boost::bind (or the standard library bind functions) would let you bind the parameter param to the function so you don't need to supply it as an argument every time.

boost::lambda is probably the most concise and flexible approach. I usually use the plain functor approach because the syntax is easier to remember. ;)

Comment: This is what I had (and was hoping to avoid) :)

Comment: hm, without boost (ouch), I don't think you can do it much shorter. In some of the cases, the std::bind_* stuff might help you, but there aren't any miraculous silver bullets. (At least until c++0x with the addition of lambda expressions)

Answer (score 4):

well when we have compilers that support C++0x lambda expresions, this becomes straightforward and minimally invasive:

```
std::for_each(myvec.begin(),myvec.end(),[&](X& item){
     item->DoWhatever(param);
});
```

and the second example may look like this:

```
std::for_each(myvec.begin(),myvec.end(),[&](X& item){   
   if(item->IsOK())      
      myvec[i]->DoWhatever(param);
});
```

Comment: That is so pity, it does not work on g++ :(. I hope in some point I will be able to use those constructions...

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/if.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>


struct A
{
  bool IsOK () { return true; }
  void DoWhatever (int param) {}
};

struct B
{
  bool IsOk (A * a) { return true; }
  void DoWhatever (A * a, int param) {}
};

typedef std::vector<A *> Myvec;

void main()
{
  Myvec myvec;
  int param = 1;
  B b;

  // first challenge using boost::bind (fnct in the same class)
  std::for_each (myvec.begin(), myvec.end(),
    boost::bind (&A::DoWhatever, _1, param));

  // first challenge using boost::bind (fnct in an external class)
  std::for_each (myvec.begin(), myvec.end(),
    boost::bind (&B::DoWhatever, &b, _1, param));

  // second challange using boost::lambda (fnct in the same class)
  std::for_each (myvec.begin(), myvec.end(),
    boost::lambda::if_then(
      boost::lambda::bind (&A::IsOK, boost::lambda::_1), 
      boost::lambda::bind (&A::DoWhatever, boost::lambda::_1, param)
    )
  );

  // second challange using boost::lambda (fnct in an external class)
  std::for_each (myvec.begin(), myvec.end(),
    boost::lambda::if_then(
      boost::lambda::bind (&B::IsOK, &b, boost::lambda::_1), 
      boost::lambda::bind (&B::DoWhatever, &b, boost::lambda::_1, param)
    )
  );

}
```

You can simplify it by using namespaces...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GCC you can define something like:

```
#define foreach(element, array) \
    for(typeof((array).begin()) element = (array).begin(), __end_##element = (array).end();\
        element != __end_##element;\
        ++element)
```

and use it after like this:

```
foreach(element, array){
    element->DoSomething(); //or (*element)->DoSomething() if type is already a pointer
}
```

I use this on a custom array but it works fine with std::vector too.